# How frequently is RandomAccessFile length updated?

Tags: java, file, java-io, randomaccessfile

I have a Java `RandomAccessFile`. I check the length of the file frequently. The file is coming from an `scp`. Therefore, the file is getting appended.

I want to know how frequently the `RandomAccessFile` is updated. Whenever I check [`RandomAccessFile.length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#length()), will get I the accurate `length`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this depends on the underlying OS and not Java. RandomAccessFile is going to report what the OS tells it is the current length. How frequently the size is updated will depend on how `scp` is buffering it's writes to the disk.

Comment: Okay. Let's say if I initialize a normal `File` object and check length. Will it be same as the `RandomAccessFile` length and the `File.length` on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method is native, I'd recommend taking a look in the OpenJDK source code. It's the closest thing you'll get to the actual implementation (unless you work for Oracle ;-).

The source can be found here (it's shared between all OS): [src/share/native/java/io/RandomAccessFile.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/native/java/io/RandomAccessFile.c#l105)

`tl;dr` Yes, it will try to find the end of the file descriptor the `RandomAccessFile` is referring to.